# Spark Structured Streaming operations on rows of a single dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

In my problem, there is a data stream of information about package delivery coming in. The data consists of "NumberOfPackages", "Action" (which can be either "Loaded", "Delivered" or "In Transit"), and "Driver".

```
val streamingData = <filtered data frame based on "Loaded" and "Delivered" Action types only>
```

The goal is to look at number of packages at the moment of loading and at the moment of delivery, and if they are not the same - execute a function that would call a REST service with the parameter of "TrackingId".

The data looks like this:

```
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------------
|NumberOfPackages |Action     |TrackingId  |Driver    |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------------
|5                |Loaded     |a           |Alex
|5                |Devivered  |a           |Alex
|8                |Loaded     |b           |James
|8                |Delivered  |b           |James
|7                |Loaded     |c           |Mark
|3                |Delivered  |c           |Mark
<...more rows in this streaming data frame...>
```

In this case, we see that by the "TrackingId" equal to "c", the number of packages loaded and delivered isn't the same, so this is where we'd need to call the REST api with the "TrackingId".

I would like to combine rows based on "TrackingId", which will always be unique for each trip. If we get the rows combined based on this tracking id, we could have two columns for number of packages, something like "PackagesAtLoadTime" and "PackagesAtDeliveryTime". Then we could compare these two values for each row and filter the dataframe by those which are not equal.

So far I have tried the groupByKey method with the "TrackingId", but I couldn't find a similar example and my experimental attempts weren't successful.

After I figure out how to "merge" the two rows with the same tracking id together and have a column for each corresponding count of packages, I could define a UDF:

```
def notEqualPackages = udf((packagesLoaded: Int, packagesDelivered: Int) => packagesLoaded!=packagesDelivered)
```

And use it to filter the rows of the dataframe to contain only those with not matching numbers:

```
streamingData.where(notEqualPackages(streamingData("packagesLoaded", streamingData("packagesDelivered")))
```

Comment: Hi - Is there a timestamp associated with the data? Have you tried self-joining your data? If you're using Spark 2.3 and above, you can join 2 streams. I'm happy to elaborate more on this if you haven't tried it already.

Also, can you please provide details on how you're making the REST API call?